# Desktop Application auto-complete

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, desktop

I am working on a .net project, (first ever for me) and I would like to do something like the AJAX.AutoCompleteExtender that I used with my WEB projects.

What should I use? is there something ready to use, Or I should go and make my own using the textbox, or combo box or something like that.

The app I am working on, is a .net application made for Windows Mobile. (Pocket PC)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this sample for creating an Auto-Complete TextBox using WinForms:

[Creating WinForms AutoComplete TextBox using C#](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html)

That should at least get you pointed in the right direction (using Events to listen for keypresses, querying your datasource, and drawing the results to screen). You might need to slightly modify things for WinCE but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @Swoosh - I don't believe so. Even if it were, you should be able to figure out how to replace the .NET 4 bits with legacy code. It'll just be a little longer.

Comment: problem, is, I'm using "2.0 CE" compact edition or something like that, because of the Windows Mobile. So I don't think this will help. But your answer is still good :) I will check to see if there's somehow a way around ...